# How to disable the notification badge on Whatsapp on LG G3?

Tags: notifications, whatsapp-messenger, lg-g3

I have LG G3. I want to disable all notifications from whatsapp, when I mute a group the only thing left is the notification badge (red number) on the app.

Browsing for "android turn off badge notification lgg3" only gives me hits regarding Samsung TouchWiz and iPhone, and I so far haven't been able to locate anything in the menu of the app either.

How can I turn off the display of unread messages on the icon of the Whatsapp app?

Comment: If you mean in nunber which is apearing on app icon in app drawer, than you can install some other launcher.

Answer (score 0):

I believe icon unread badges are managed by your laucher and not by the app itself. Try looking in your home launcher's options. For example [nova launcher](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.teslacoilsw.launcher&hl=en) allows to control this setting through [TeslaUnread](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.teslacoilsw.notifier&hl=en).

Answer (score 0):

Head to your settings, apps, and look for whatsapp. Tap it, and untick "show notification" and you are done.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if anyone still needs help but I was able to diable the app badge notifications by using ROM Toolbox Pro.

From the main ROM Toolbox Pro screen go to: App Manager > [Tap on app that you want to remove app badge notification] > Swipe from right to left until you are under 'Advanced' > Advanced Freeze > Under 'Receivers', tap on anything similar to 'NotificationBroadcastReceiver' > Tap 'Ok' to disable